# dynamiclly set the function an event listner should call

Tags: javascript, eval

I've got a simple array of options which essentially dictate which buttons should be visible through the web application at any point.

So for home the array looks like: Step 1

```
if (view === "home") {
  visibleCommands = [];
  visibleCommands[0] = "contact";
  visibleCommands[1] = "about";
}
setVisibility(visibleCommands);
```

Then I loop through the array: Step 2

```
setVisibility(visibleCommands) {
  var i;
  for (i in visibleCommands) {
    document.getElementById(visibleCommands[i].style.display = "inline";
  }
  addEvents(visibleCommands);
}
```

Then lastly, for the visible commands I want to add separate event listeners: Step 3

```
addEvents(visibleCommands) {
  var i;
  for (i in visibleCommands) {
    document.getElementById(visibleCommands[i]).addEventListener("click", visibleCommands[i], false);  
  }
}
```

However the event doesn't seem to get hooked up to the element in the view, if I change this line to:

```
document.getElementById(visibleCommands[i]).addEventListener("click", contact, false);
```

Then it correctly gets hooked up to the element and the contact() function gets called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
document.getElementById(visibleCommands[i]).addEventListener("click", visibleCommands[i], false);
```

`visibleCommands[i]` is the **id**:

```
document.getElementById(visibleCommands[i])
```

`visibleCommands[i]` is the **click callback**:

```
.addEventListener("click", visibleCommands[i], false);
```

How can it be?

`"contact"` and `contact` are two diffrent things. The first is a string with `contact` value, while the second is a reference to a function

---

Another thing:

```
document.getElementById(visibleCommands[i].style.display = "inline";
```

There is a missing `)` in the `getElementById` function call:

```
document.getElementById(visibleCommands[i]).style.display = "inline";
```

Comment: console.log(visibleCommands[i]) inside the for loop gives me "contact"

Comment: Therefore the resulting output should be: addEventListener("click", contact, false);

Comment: @CLiown. See the update, you can use `eval`-  `eval(visibleCommands[i])` to get the function reference out of the string, but you should design your code better, so you won't use it..

Comment: Is it possible to 'dynamically' set the string to be a reference to a function?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you binding the handler?

```
document.getElementById(visibleCommands[i]).addEventListener("click", visibleCommands[i], false);
```

The 2nd argument in the above line is a string which is not correct. It should be the handler function.

Try something like below,

```
document.getElementById(visibleCommands[i]).addEventListener("click", function () {
   alert('Clicked');
}, false);
```

You can read about [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Also use `.push` proper way to add elements to an array. See below,

```
visibleCommands.push("contact");
visibleCommands.push("about");
```